# extract element from xml using xmlstarlet

Tags: bash, xmlstarlet

I'm trying to extract the "enclosure url" from the xml below using xmlstarlet.

I found this [Extract values from XML using xmlstarlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798348/extract-values-from-xml-using-xmlstarlet) which has given me a couple of pointers but I'm a little confused as to why ias=http://www.oracle.com/ias-instance is set. Shouldn't the element be referenced? not the content?

Could something similar be used against the xml below or am I barking up the wrong tree?

```
    <rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>Wrestle Me</title>
        <description>
        </description>
        <acast:showId>fba44d70-2a73-44d9-8bf9-726e9fcc2b3e</acast:showId>
        <acast:showUrl>wrestleme</acast:showUrl>
        <link>https://play.acast.com/s/wrestleme</link>
        <atom:link rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" href="https://rss.acast.com/wrestleme"/>
        <pingback:receiver>https://interaction.acast.com/pingback</pingback:receiver>
        <lastBuildDate>Thu, 18 Jul 2019 04:05:27 GMT</lastBuildDate>
        <pubDate>Thu, 18 Jul 2019 04:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
        <ttl>30</ttl>
        <language>en</language>
        <copyright>
        </copyright>
        <docs>https://www.acast.com/wrestleme</docs>
        <acast:signature key="EXAMPLE" algorithm="aes-256-cbc">9w1/WFWZb9YCoFYTxRGhxA==</acast:signature>
        <acast:network>
        </acast:network>
        <acast:settings>
        </acast:settings>
        <image>
        </image>
        <itunes:image href="https://thumborcdn.acast.com/66RENnKTBsvtDbIhZez9wTij8hg=/1500x1500/https://mediacdn.acast.com/assets/fba44d70-2a73-44d9-8bf9-726e9fcc2b3e/-jbxjj7ek-whatsapp_image_2018-01-02_at_11-16-53.jpeg"/>
        <itunes:subtitle>
        </itunes:subtitle>
        <itunes:type>episodic</itunes:type>
        <itunes:author>Radio Stakhanov</itunes:author>
        <itunes:summary></itunes:summary>
        <itunes:owner>
        </itunes:owner>
        <itunes:explicit>yes</itunes:explicit>
        <itunes:keywords/>
        <itunes:category text="Sports & Recreation">
        </itunes:category>
        <media:credit role="author">Radio Stakhanov</media:credit>
        <media:description type="html">
        </media:description>
        <item>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>It just makes me sad - WrestleMania XX part 4</title>
            <acast:episodeId>b51a603d-8980-4cef-9a6c-b5cf0e5038a0</acast:episodeId>
            <acast:episodeUrl>itjustmakesmesad-wrestlemaniaxxpart4</acast:episodeUrl>
            <itunes:subtitle>
            </itunes:subtitle>
            <itunes:summary>
            </itunes:summary>
            <guid isPermaLink="false">b51a603d-8980-4cef-9a6c-b5cf0e5038a0</guid>
            <pubDate>Thu, 11 Jul 2019 01:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
            <itunes:duration>00:40:32</itunes:duration>
            <itunes:keywords/>
            <itunes:explicit>no</itunes:explicit>
            <itunes:episodeType>full</itunes:episodeType>
            <itunes:image href="https://thumborcdn.acast.com/iRcL017SnqZUc-ne7xmt6JnGZQw=/3000x3000/https://mediacdn.acast.com/assets/b51a603d-8980-4cef-9a6c-b5cf0e5038a0/cover-image-jwamv8ll-wrestleme_1500.jpeg"/>
            <description>
            </description>
            <acast:settings>
            </acast:settings>
            <link>
            </link>
            <enclosure url="https://media.acast.com/wrestleme/itjustmakesmesad-wrestlemaniaxxpart4/media.mp3" length="38927363" type="audio/mpeg"/>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: The `xml` namespaces like `acast`, `itunes`, `pingback` etc are not defined.

Comment: Plus, this line is invalid: `<itunes:category text="Sports & Recreation">`. It should have been `<itunes:category text="Sports &amp; Recreation">`

Comment: After fixing the above issue of `&amp;`, you can work with this: `sed -r 's|(<\/?[^ :]*):|\1_|g' test.rss | xmlstarlet sel -t -v //enclosure/@url`